# Являются ли публикации статей в Notebook Anaconda Python общепринятыми в западной научной среде?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Изучаю [курс](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/learn-to-code) по анализу данных.
Там статьи с интерактивными примерами на Pyton.

Являются ли публикации статей в Notebook Anaconda Python общепринятыми в западной научной среде? Как, например, некоторое время назад популярным был редактор научных текстов Дональда Кнута TeX. Статьи, сверстанные в TeX, без проблем принимались к публикации научными журналами.

Comment: Общепринятыми в научной среде являются публикации статей в рецензируемых журналах (см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80). 
Нигде не регламентировано использование именно IPython или Jupyter Notebook, просто (например, для анализа данных) вывод всего и сразу на одной странице может оказаться удобней, чем поиск всех файлов с графиками в рабочей папке.
Еще одной общепринятой вещью в научной среде точно можно считать недостаток времени - ipython помогает его экономить, как и множество других инструментов, вот и все.